# Displaying icons

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display a set of icons in a java project using a grouplayout and Jlabel, but the problem is that when I run the project I got this [image: result]

And I'd like to display it like this, And I also need to minimize the icons.
[image: expected result]

Here's my code :

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ImageIconLabelEx extends JFrame {

    public ImageIconLabelEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Empty.png"));
        JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Empty.png"));
        JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Empty.png"));
        JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Empty.png"));
        JLabel lbl5 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Empty.png"));
        JLabel lbl6 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Empty.png"));
        JLabel lbl7 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Full.png"));
        JLabel lbl8 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Full.png"));
        JLabel lbl9 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Full.png"));
        JLabel lbl10 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("imgs/Full.png"));

        createLayout(lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4, lbl5, lbl6, lbl7, lbl8, lbl9,lbl10 );


        setTitle("Icons");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);        

        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(false);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2])
                .addComponent(arg[3])
                .addComponent(arg[4])
                .addComponent(arg[5])
                .addComponent(arg[6])
                .addComponent(arg[7])
                .addComponent(arg[8])
                .addComponent(arg[9])

        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                .addComponent(arg[0])
                .addComponent(arg[1])
                .addComponent(arg[2])
                .addComponent(arg[3])
                .addComponent(arg[4])
                .addComponent(arg[5])
                .addComponent(arg[6])
                .addComponent(arg[7])
                .addComponent(arg[8])
                .addComponent(arg[9])

        );

        pack();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            ImageIconLabelEx ex = new ImageIconLabelEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you want to change.  Is the problem that the wrong images are being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a GroupLayout. It is one of the more complex to use and you get incorrect results if you use the wrong constraints.

Instead, use a `GridLayout` wrapped in a panel to preserve the size of the icons:

Something like:

```
JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
labelPanel.add(label1);
labelPanel.add(label2);
...
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel(); // defaults to FlowLayout
wrapper.add( iconPanel );
frame.add( wrapper );
```

> I also need to minimize the icons.

Not sure what that means, but if you want to change the size you need to read in each image using `ImageIO` and then you can use the `Image.getScaledInstance(...)` method to resize the image. Then you create the ImageIcon using the scaled image.